# Compose: running a container that exits

Tags: docker, fig, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml with postgres and a web app (ghost). I would like to run a container between postgres and ghost to initialize postgres, add a database and user permissions, and exit.

My database initialization code looks something like:

```
ghostdb:
  extends:
    file: ./compose/ghost.yml
    service: ghostdb
  links:
    - postgres
  volumes:
    - ./ghost-db/volumes/sql:/sql
```

Which in turn runs

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Importing SQL
until pg_isready -h postgres; do
    sleep 1
done

for f in /sql/*.sql; do
    echo Importing $f
    psql -h postgres -f $f
done
```

I know I can extend postgres to add this functionality, but I would rather separate these two concerns. So I have two questions:

Is there a preferable pattern for initializing a database? Is it possible to run a container that exits between postgres and ghost?

Full repository can be viewed here: https://github.com/devpaul/ghost-compose

Comment: Why do you want to add an extra entity? PostgreSQL can be perfectly initialized with a script/dump/etc in the `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: In this case I have a production repository for postgres and I have 2 separate ghost repositories that both use the postgres container that are deployed separately. In each production ghost deployment they need to gain permissions and update the database and I would prefer that not be tightly coupled with the postgres repo.